# Swift 3 - Animation

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewanimation

I am animating an image across the bottom of my iPad app.  Currently the imageView is animated using the following code snippet:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0,
                   options: [.repeat, .curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut],
                   animations: {

             self.imageView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

    },
             completion: nil
)
```

I have an integer intVal = 0;

I need to change the image of my image view based on the value of intVal.  How can I compare the intVal and change the image before the animation starts?

Ideally, the final code snippet would look like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0,
                   options: [.repeat, .curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut],
                   animations: {

             self.imageView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

    },
             completion: 
             if(intVal == 1){
                imageView.image = differentImg.png;
             }
             ...
             else if(intVal == 10){
                imageView.image = AnotherDifferentImg.png;
             }
)
```

EDIT:

This method is called ONCE in ViewDidAppear.  The animation repeats (as the .repeat option indicates) every 5 seconds (as the duration indicates). The picture must determine if it needs to change every time the animation repeats.

Comment: I assume you meant 1-3, 4-6, and 7-9 ... that being said, how come you can't do this: if (intVal - 1) / 3 == 0 { imageView.image = firstimage.png} else if (intVal - 1) / 3 == 1 { imageView.image = secondimage.png} else if (intVal - 1) / 3 == 2 { imageView.image = thirdimage.png}

Comment: @brw59 This question does not ask how to determine the int.  I need to logically determine the image based on the int.

Comment: the if statements assign the image based on the intVal, there was no assigning of the intVal in my comment above

Comment: @brw59 See edit.  The UIview.animate occurs in ViewDidAppear.  therefore it is only called once.  if I add that if/Else construct, the picture will only change the very first time the animation is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a method that will first check the value and then animate view without repeating option but call itself in completion block.

```
func animateImageView {
    if(intVal == 1){
        imageView.image = differentImg.png;
    }
     ...
    else if(intVal == 10){
        imageView.image = AnotherDifferentImg.png;
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0,
               options: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut],
               animations: {

         self.imageView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

},
         completion: animateImageView())
```

And call this method in viewDidAppear

Comment: This worked.  For other viewers... remember that you must reset the imageView position at the top of this method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a timer to accomplish your goal, because you not only need the animation, but also some other logic. So ask timer to handle your repeat, and then do other jobs inside

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 6, repeats: true) {
    (_) in
    //Set image first base on intVal
    if inVal == 1 {
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "a.png")
    }else{
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "b.png")
    }

    //Then start animation
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.imageView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This worked for a few iterations.  However, the 6 second timer interval eventually creates a huge seperation from the 5 second animation duration.  The Completion block implementation is the common practice answer.